# Error: unexpected input in the model with R2OpenBUGS

Tags: r, bayesian, debug-symbols, r2winbugs

I am trying to run this model under R for bayesian inference modelling:

```
model {
for (i in 1:N) {
logit(theta[i]) i- alpha + beta*d[i]
y[i] ∼ dbin(theta[i], n[i])
}
alpha∼ dbeta(1, 1)
beta ∼ dbeta(1, 1)}
```

I have previously created a list with the values of y, n, d and N:

```
list(y=c(67, 43, 193, 250, 141) , n=c(282, 225, 290, 261, 141) , 
d=c(0, 62.5, 125, 250, 500) , N=5)
```

and :

```
 list(alpha=0.1, beta=0.01)
```

libraries installed:

library(R2WinBUGS) and library(coda)

I get this error message:

```
model {
Error: unexpected '{' in "model {"
for (i in 1:N) {
+    logit(theta[i]) i- alpha + beta*d[i]
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"for (i in 1:N) {
logit(theta[i]) i"
y[i] ∼ dbin(theta[i], n[i])}
Error: unexpected input in "        y[i] ∼"
alpha∼ dbeta(1, 1)
Error: unexpected input in "alpha∼"
beta ∼ dbeta(1, 1)}
Error: unexpected input in "beta ∼"
```

Can someone please advise a solution?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  I use JAGS rather than BUGS, so I can't be sure, but a few things about your code strike me as peculiar.  It looks like you're trying to fit a dose response model.  You normally supply the model in a character variable, but there's no indication in the code above that you are doing so.  The `i-` in `logit(theta[i]) i- alpha + beta*d[i]` looks odd.